# functional bind operation in C preprocessor

Tags: c++, c, bind, c-preprocessor

I have a macro like this (it's coming from an actual useful use case, but I've been playing with simplified cases):

```
#define MY_MACRO(M)  M(3) M(5) M(7)
#define MULTIPLY_BY_2(A)  (2*A)
```

I can then write

```
MY_MACRO(MULTIPLY_BY_2)
// -> (2*3) (2*5) (2*7)
```

Cool! What I want is this:

```
#define MULTIPLY(A,B) (A*B)
MY_MACRO(BIND(MULTIPLY, 2))
```

To get the same result as above. What could BIND be? I've tried some hacks, and can report that this IS almost possible (which I find amazing). But it's not pretty, and not general. Can this be done *well*? (I.e. build some real functional facilities purely in CPP?) Can it be done well enough to bind a bound macro?

Perhaps what I'm really asking is whether there are tools like this in any preprocessor libraries that you are aware of? I didn't find anything quite like this in Boost.

Comment: Trying to do too much with the preprocessor can make the code a nightmare to debug / understand in the future.

Comment: The Boost stuff is based on Vesa Karvonen's work, which evidently implemented a complete functional language in the preprocessor, with lexical environments, tail recursion, etc. So I'm skeptical about "not find anything like this in Boost". Are you sure? Not likely under that nice and simple partial application syntax, though.

Answer (score 4):

You can't ask macro programming to be pretty, sorry.

Comment: Beauty is in the eye of the beholder. But OK, forget "pretty", let's just stay with "general". Can something like preprocessor BIND be implemented to work in general? Is there such a thing in Boost-Preprocessor library?

Answer (score 2):

Unbalanced parentheses can do a sort of bind operation, but then the call syntax is different from a normal macro. It needs an extra close paren.

```
#define BIND( op, arg ) op ( arg,
#define MULTIPLY( a, b ) ( (a) * (b) )

#define MULTIPLY_BY_2 BIND( MULTIPLY, 2 )

MULTIPLY_BY_2( 5 )) // note two close parens
```

http://ideone.com/EQvs2

You can try defining more macros to generate the close paren as appropriate, but there is probably a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that I completely understand what kind of functionality you want to achieve, but the following suits your example:

```
#define MULTIPLY_2(X) (2*(X))
#define POW_2(X) ((X)*(X))
#define BIND(OP, NUM) OP ## _ ## NUM
```

for `MULTIPLY_2` & Co watch that you always put parenthesis around the argument to be sure that this has the evaluation order that you want. And also beware that with you general strategy arguments may be evaluated several times, which can be a serious bug if the expression contains side effects.

Better would be to have your basic operations as inline functions and compose the function call with the macros

```
#define MULTIPLY_2(X) multiply2(X)
#define POW_2(X) pow2(X)
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but no, the simple example with numbers is just an example; in reality, I may need to bind a string or an artibtrary expression (instead of the literal 2).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, yes. In the [Order library](https://github.com/VesaKarvonen/order-pp), you could express the above like this:

```
#include <order/interpreter.h>

#define ORDER_PP_DEF_8my_mac ORDER_PP_FN( \
8fn(8M, 8seq(8ap(8M, 3), 8ap(8M, 5), 8ap(8M, 7))) )

#define ORDER_PP_DEF_8bind ORDER_PP_FN( \
8fn(8F, 8A, 8fn(8X, 8ap(8F, 8A, 8X)) ) )

#define ORDER_PP_DEF_8multiply ORDER_PP_FN( \
8fn(8L, 8R, 8times(8L, 8R)) )      // (already built-in as 8times)

ORDER_PP (
    8my_mac(8bind(8multiply, 2))   // -> (6)(10)(14)
)
```

That's with a manual definition of `bind` and `multiply`; Order also supports ML-style partial evaluation natively, so you could just write:

```
ORDER_PP ( 8my_mac(8times(2)) )    // -> (6)(10)(14)
```

Aside from the slightly weird syntax imposed by the C preprocessor, the language is basically a fairly straightforward Lisp/ML hybrid with support for many common functional idioms.